# Highlight/ change background color of cell using another data

Tags: extjs6, extjs6-classic

I have 2 columns like TPF and TPF_FLAG which i get from my rest service. TPF_FLAG will be 0 or 1 which indicates that should i change the background color of TPF cell or not. If it 1 that TPF cell background should be red. How do i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the renderer on the column like this:

```
{
      text: 'TD',
      dataIndex: 'TPF',
      renderer: function (value, metaData, record) {
          if(record.get('TPF_FLAG') == 1){
             metaData.tdStyle = 'background-color: red';
          }
          return value;
      }
  }
```

And note, that the value you return from the renderer will be shown in the column.

Also, you can look at the [docs](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.2/classic/Ext.grid.column.Column.html#cfg-renderer) for more things you can do with `renderer`.

Comment: Can a add class to metaData instead of writing style directly?